# Oracle query for selection

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table say Variables, in which a column exists with name "name". The field has values like-

```
    abc_R01
    abc_R02
    abc_R03
    pqrs_R01
    pqrs_R02
    xyz_R01
    xyz_R02
    xyz_R03
    xyz_R04
```

Now my selection criteria is like that I have to select latest variable names of each, i.e. can I fire a single/complex query to obtain result like-

```
    abc_R03
    pqrs_R02
    xyz_R04
```

Or I need to process it via my code, Here _Rxx denotes revision of my variables.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
select 
  Col
from
(
  select
    Col,
    row_number() over (partition BY substr(Col, 0, instr(Col, '_')) order by regexp_substr(col, '\d+$') DESC) rn
  from YourTable
)x where rn=1;
```

Check below query in 10 G

```
select 
  Col
from
(
  select
    Col,
    row_number() over (partition BY substr(Col, 0, instr(Col, '_')) order by substr(col, instr(col, 'R')+1) DESC) rn
  from YourTable
)x where rn=1;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/66c75/3)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs, but this query is giving error on Oracle-10i
ORA-00904: "REGEXP_SUBSTR": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Answer (score 1):

```
select name
from
(
select 
  substr("name",0,length("name")-1) as n1,max("name") as name
from Table1
   group by substr("name",0,length("name")-1)
)t
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0a63cf/9)**

Comment: I think the result goes when adding a name `xyz_R20`.

Answer (score 1):

This too will help you,

```
WITH t(NAME) AS
(
SELECT 'abc_R01' FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 'abc_R02' FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 'abc_R03' FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 'pqrs_R01' FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 'pqrs_R02' FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 'xyz_R01' FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 'xyz_R02' FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 'xyz_R03' FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 'xyz_R04' FROM dual
)
SELECT NAME
FROM (
     SELECT substr(NAME, 0, instr(NAME, 'R')),
            MAX(NAME) NAME
     FROM  t
     GROUP BY substr(NAME, 0, instr(NAME, 'R'))
     );
```